# How to publish list workflow with service account using SharePoint designer 2013 in to SharePoint Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Currently list workflows used in my site are published using my own account, I would like to publish list workflow with service account e.g "svcTest" using SharePoint designer 2013 in to SharePoint Office 365 site, How do i achieve this?

Comment: I have added it to comment you can accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login/connect to SPO site through designer with service account and publish the workflows.